# Problem with installing Pear (XAMPP)

Tags: pear

Hello I installed the latest version of XAMPP (1.7.4) on my windows xp system.
Now when i want to install Pear:

```
k:\xampp\php>go-pear.bat
```

I am confronted with the following error:

> manifest cannot be larger than 100 MB
>   in phar
>   "K:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar"PH P
>   Warning: 
>   require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php):
>   failed to open stream: phar error:
>   invalid url or non-existent phar
>   "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in
>   K:\xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line
>   1236
>
> Warning:
>   require_once(phar://go-pear.phar/index.php):
>   failed to open stream: pha r error:
>   invalid url or non-existent phar
>   "phar://go-pear.phar/index.php" in K:\
>   xampp\php\PEAR\go-pear.phar on line
>   1236 Press any key to continue

Line 1236 on in the go-pear.phar is this:

> require_once 'phar://go-pear.phar/index.php';
>   __HALT_COMPILER();<

And after the last < there is a weird character sign. And if i take away that charachter I can't it doesn't help. She the image below for the character.

[image]

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick update from IRC: The current work-around is that he doesn't need to run `go-pear.bat` because PEAR is actually included in Xampp.

However, it's recommended to update the included install regardless:

```
C:\XAMPP\PHP>pear upgrade PEAR
```

**Updated, 2011-03-16**: We also fixed the download link (for the .phar) so e.g. Internet Explorer opens a "Save As..." dialog instead of displaying the file contents. So this should take care of the file corrupting on some systems.

Comment: Hello Till, I did an upgrade. But this did not solve my problem.

Comment: Hey, can you add what the error is now? Because you have pear installed. ;-)